# Syntax Highlighting, error detection and method navigation for Java not working in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have imported the project into the intellij and what I have found is that the Syntax Highlighting, error detection and method navigation for Java not working in IntelliJ.

I have tried many ways

1. File->Invalidate Cache Restart
2. Rebuild etc.
3. File->Mark directory as source root(It shows all the project in red colour)

But none of them are successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all of your classes are under the module `Content Root`, and mark the root `Source Root`.

[Source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167299#comment=27-1877392)